# I want to make the second button click event to work only after the first button click event works

Tags: javascript, html, button

I want to make the second button click event to work only after the first button click event works . Second button's click event must not work before clicking the first button.
And also want to a text box on first button for past a url 
Means when viewrs didn't paste url in text box and click on ok
The second button didn't work
Like 
Nomigamer.com use in hes site

Comment: Please provide the code You have tried, and describe what it is the problem.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Bro. I cant provide code because i didn't know html.

Comment: I make site by YouTube. I all is good but i want a script wait i send u a pic

Comment: Bro - so this is good point to start learning html ! :)

Comment: https://www.nomigamer.com/2019/02/garena-free-fire-hackmod-apk.html?m=1 open this link he's used this in hes site in bottom of the post

Comment: Thnx bro than you so much  but now go this link    ... https://www.nomigamer.com/2019/02/garena-free-fire-hackmod-apk.html?m=1

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by create **flag**.

Default value of **flag** is false, when you click on first button, **flag** is true.

When click on second button it will check if **flag** is enable or not, if enable you can process second button.

Let's take a example:

```
var flag = false;
$("#firstButton").click(function(){
  flag = true;
  //Implement code for first button here
});

$("#secondButton").click(function(event){
  if(flag === false) {
      event.preventDefault();
  }
  //Implement code for second button here
});
```

For second question. I still don't know what you mean. Could you describe it more detail?

**Edit**

Added full code as your request

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" id="input1" value="12345">
    <input type="text" id="input2">
    <button id="button1">First button</button>
    <button id="button2">Second button</button>

    <script>
        var flag = false;
        //Because first button has id button1 so I use #button1 to handle event click
        $("#button1").click(function(){
            //Enable flag
            flag = true;
            // Because first input has id input1 so I use #input1 to get it element
            // $("#input1").val() will get value of first input
            var firstInputValue = $("#input1").val();
            // Set value of first input is empty
            $("#input1").val("");
            // Set value of input 1 for input 2
            $("#input2").val(firstInputValue);
        });

        $("#button2").click(function(event){
          //If flag is disabled then exit function, Don't process anything.
          if(flag === false) {
              event.preventDefault();
              return;
          }
          // If flag is enable then set value input1 = input2 and clear input2
          var secondInputValue = $("#input2").val();
          $("#input2").val("");
          $("#input1").val(secondInputValue);
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

It has some bug still not fix. Your job to find solution to do that :D

Comment: Can you please type full code please don't because i didn't know how to do this i know little bit html

Comment: I send you a link where i see that buttons. I a person type tgat script in he's website here is his link.... Read how to unlock limk https://www.nomigamer.com/2019/02/garena-free-fire-hackmod-apk.html?m=1

Comment: I just added code example hope this will help you.
I just checked your url. This is not a link, just a text with blue color
<span style="color: blue;">Downloading link</span>
A link will have format as bellow:
<a href="https://www.yourlink.com">This is a link</a>